# Cross reference in Google Sheets (2 sheets with varying length columns and potential duplicates)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First off, many thanks in advance!  This is my first post.  I am brand new to google sheets as well.

My data is the following.  One sheet contains a column of last names only.  The last names columns does include duplicate last names.  My main sheet contains a column of first and last names which is about 3x as long as the list of last names only.

I would like to generate a boolean column for pivoting purposes which cross references the last name list with the full names.  If any of the last names are partially matched to a full name, then the boolean is a 1 or TRUE.

```
Cross Reference:  Doe & Mann

Jim Smith
0
Jane Doe
1
John Rich
0
Joe Bills
0
Brian The Mann
1
Bill Downs
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A1:A11, TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, C1:C11)))
```

Paste this in the column where you want TRUE/FALSE. Replace A1:A11 with your full names list, C1:C11 with your cross-reference.

If you would like empty spaces, or customize the response, use:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A11, TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, C1:C11)), "TRUE TEXT", "FALSE TEXT"))
```

Comment: Many thanks!!  This worked very nicely aside from the case sensitivity.  I converted all the "data" to lower case and just let it loose.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="";;N(REGEXMATCH(A1:A; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; E:E)))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had issues with the formula finding incorrect matches.  I am still looking into why...